# IPython.html.widgets: saving the value for later

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I started using IPython.html.widgets to explore impact of various parameters on distributions. I would like to plot a figure using one of the values. For example:

```
def myHistogram(bins):
    plt.hist(mydata,bins) 
    return fig

from IPython.html.widgets import interact
interact(myHistogram,bins = (10,50,5))

fig=plt.gcf()
```

For example, after examining my distribution I conclude that for this specific case I would like to have 25 bins.

```
fig.savefig(fig_name.jpg)
```

saves the default plot. Is there any way to force it to save figure using the last value from the slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trouble is that `plt.hist()` creates a new figure each time, so your `fig` variable is left unchanged. It should work if you modify the figure instead:

```
# Get the figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def myHistogram(bins):
    # Clear any previous data, and plot the new histogram
    ax.clear()
    ax.hist(mydata, bins)
    fig.show()  # Seems to be necessary

interact(myHistogram, bins=(10, 50, 5))
```

(I haven't actually tested this)